# External HDD disk must be turned on twice always

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

My external 3.5 inch, 3 TB hard disk must be **always** started twice. Each time power it up (after about 2-3 days of not using it, as it acts as backup drive only) it starts emitting a very constant *ticking* sound and it is not recognizable by any computer it is plugged into. Once powered down and powered up again (restarted) problem is gone and I can access it for no problems.

This situation started to happen for past 2-3 weeks *each time*. For past two years there were no problems at all with this disk or described situation happens once per 2-3 months.

I assume, this is a symptom of disk live going to an end. But I still wonder, how it is possible, that this patterns is so extremely repeatable -- disk refuses to work (ticking sound) *every* first run and there are no problems at all *every* second run. In the past, I had similar problems with many disks (and it ended up with this replacement in each of this scenarios), but ticking sound was emitted at random runs.

Also -- is there anything, that I can do for this disk, except for replacing it with brand new one?

**EDIT**: *This isn't an ordinary external drive, but rather a standalone Linux-based video player. For an unknown reasons to me, the ticking sound does not start to be emitted before 3-5 minutes since initial power on -- i.e. not before entire Linux and player firmware is loaded and run.*

Comment: `how it is possible` .. it's a micro controller with very tiny sensitive electronics .. it's possible its controllers and firmware get just enough juice the first go around to charge up the rest of the circuit, but due to a faulty transistor or IC somewhere, it doesn't properly flow .. disconnect power and the circuit can discharge "just right" to give the circuit "proper" flow the 2nd power cycle .. `tl;dr` .. microscopic electronics can cause ALL sorts of issues, it's time for you to backup and get a new drive ...

Comment: Ticking is a mechanical problem; your drive is failing

Comment: Agree with @Ramhound that a drive issue is the most likely. They really are incredibly finely tuned devices and failures are very common, especially when moving the drives often. However, you should also check that the device is getting enough power.

Comment: Do you only let it go for a few seconds before you power cycle it again?  My first thought was heat: after running for a bit it warms up then things expand and get into the right place.  That's not very likely though if you cycle it very quickly.

Comment: @psusi Nope! I let it run for about 2-3 minutes before I power it off and on again.

Comment: Try doing it within a few seconds and see if it still shows the same pattern.   If not, then heat seems likely.

Comment: @psusi I can't -- see the edited question -- the _ticking_ sound does not start to be emitted before 3-5 minutes since initial power on.

Comment: Your new information doesn't really change very much.  You still have a mechanical device that is starting to fail you should replace that drive.  I can almost guarantee there isn't anything special about the drive.